# Determining which user restarted a Windows server

Tags: windows, logging, reboot

Is it possible to determine who restarted a Windows server?  I'm looking through the Event System Log for "6006" events which correspond with a reboot, but the user is listed as "N/A".  I tried to tie it back to logins in the Security Log by time, but there are too many of them for that to be an accurate method.

Answer (score 7):

Filter your log and search for ID : 1074 with Source : user32
in below you can see who initiated restart process